# Rewrite URL is not working from localhost

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I tried hiding my .php extensions with .htaccess at first.. It did work fine after including this in the file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

and also including this in my function.php

```
//==== Strip .php extension from requested URI  
function strip_php_extension()  
{  
  $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  
  $ext = substr(strrchr($uri, '.'), 1);  
  if ($ext == 'php')  
  {  
    $url = substr($uri, 0, strrpos($uri, '.'));  
    redirect($url);  
  } 
}  

//==== Redirect. Try PHP header redirect, then Java, then http redirect
function redirect($url)  
{  
  if (!headers_sent())  
  {  
    /* If headers not yet sent => do php redirect */  
    header('Location: '.$url);  
    exit;  
  }  
  else  
  {
    /* If headers already sent => do java redirect */  
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';  
    echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';  
    echo '</script>';  

    /* If java is disabled => do html redirect */  
    echo '<noscript>';  
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='.$url.'" />';  
    echo '</noscript>';  
    exit;  
  }  
}
```

Thing is the url for dynamic pages did not change.. I still have page.php?p=5
and blog.php?post=5 not changing to page?p=5 and blog?post=5..

I do want to change the above dynamic pages url to something nice like www.yourdomian.com/5 for page.php and www.yourdomain.com/blog/5 for the blog, but this is not reading it from my ReWrite rule in htacces

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ page.php?p=$1
```

Kindly point me in the right direction as to what am doing wrong. and how to fix it.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located?

Comment: root of My Application. where the index.php is

Comment: And where is `about-us.php`? Inside `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyApp` or `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/`

Comment: inside /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MyApp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in `/MyApp/.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /MyApp/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.php\?([a-z])=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  /blog\.php\?post=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ blog/%1? [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/?$ blog.php?post=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-z])/([^/.]+)/?$ page.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It works fine for the page.php, but I have two questions. on my dynamic page (page.php) there ought to be two GET request .. page.php?p=$1 and page.php?s=$1.. How do I include the last condition in the htaccess file? And the blog rewrite condition outputs a 500 error. Thanks for coming through.

Comment: foobar can't be present in both.. is there a way to treat both urls as different elements

Comment: do you mind writing conditions for that please but with the extension page.php.. since that i sthe parent page

Comment: This is not suporting page.php?s=  only page.php?p= is being supported by the rewrite condition

Comment: Yes this does but it affects all the included file as they can't be traced.. It means me editing the includes file which also affects other pages... Been trying and not trying too..

Comment: Yes... They have to go one step further outside the directory to display correctly..

Comment: <?php require ('includes/header.php');?>  header.php     <!-- Responsive CSS Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">

    <!-- Css3 Transitions Styles  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">  page.php is sitting in the same directory as includes and css.. page/m/page1 means page 1 is sitting two directory from the home directory thereby rendering the include files useless

Comment: You can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/MyApp/" />`  to fix css/js issue. php include has nothing to with rewrite rules.

Comment: Can't I completely remove the little strings in front of the url www.domain.com/p/about-us to www.domain.com/about-us and also www.domain.com/s/welcome to www.domain.com/welcome

Comment: the blog rewrite condition does not seem to work anymore with the new condition.. Kindly check and see what went wrong please.

Comment: What is new condition? Also I suggest creating a new question for additional problem since long discussions in comment section are not liked by SO moderators.